# Merge 2 columns and sum inside the column

Tags: mysql

I have a Table like:

```
| ColA | ColB |
|------|------|
|  1   |  3   |
|  2   |  4   |
|  3   |  5   |
|  4   |  6   |
|  5   |  7   |
```

I would like to combine them into 1 column then calculate the cumulative sum of the merged column as:

```
| Mer  |  Sum Col  | 
|------|-----------| 
|   1  |     1     |
|   2  |     3     |
|   3  |     6     |
|   4  |    10     |
|   5  |    15     |
|   6  |    21     |
|   7  |    28     |
```

I can create the Mer column using Union as:

```
SELECT colA FROM x UNION SELECT colB FROM x;
```

but have no idea to create Sum Col, could anyone help me for this?

Comment: you've done the cumulative sum of ColA. Does ColB take part in your problem? If A ColA is just a series this can be done using [maths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Answer (score 0):

Just use inner query in SELECT clause.

```
SELECT 
  tbl.Mer, 
  (SELECT SUM(tbl1.Mer) FROM your_table_name tbl1 WHERE tbl1.Mer<=tbl.Mer) AS SumCol
FROM your_table_name tbl
```

With assumption that `your_table_name` contains this record:

```
| Mer  |
|------|
|   1  |
|   2  |
|   3  |
|   4  |
|   5  |
|   6  |
|   7  |
```

Edit: with assumption that your UNION query is as such:

```
SELECT colA AS Mer FROM x UNION SELECT colB AS Mer FROM x;
```

then we can adjust the previous query to:

```
SELECT 
  tbl.Mer, 
  (
    SELECT SUM(tbl1.Mer) 
    FROM (SELECT colA AS Mer FROM x UNION SELECT colB AS Mer FROM x) tbl1 
    WHERE tbl1.Mer<=tbl.Mer
  ) AS SumCol
FROM 
  (SELECT colA AS Mer FROM x UNION SELECT colB AS Mer FROM x) tbl
```

Comment: Thanks, but my table not contain Mer column yet. Could you please advise how to have the output with these 2 columns?